# Azure Function OAuth works in Postman but returns "No permission" in browser

Tags: azure, .net-core, dynamics-crm

I have developed an Azure Function which is authenticated using an existing Azure AD app registration. When I access the API using OAuth authentication from Postman, everything works smoothly. However, when I try to access the same API endpoint through a browser, it returns a "You do not have permission to view this directory or page" error.

What could be causing this inconsistency between Postman and the browser, and how can I resolve it? I've verified that the Azure AD app registration permissions are correctly configured. Is there something specific I need to configure for browser access, or is there another potential issue I should investigate? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.